# Get RDS information in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

What is the best way to get DB related information like DB size, DB utilization total time etc.. in AWS from aws-sdk.

I am using [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk). I need to fetch DB details using this to showcase DB related data on frontend

I have researched and found [Cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#getMetricStatistics-property). But this doesn't provide any DB related information. Is there any other alternative way or best way. Please suggest.

I need DB size and DB utilization total time

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature in RDS called Performance Insights. Here is the link for you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.html

Note: first you have to [enable Performance Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Enabling.html) feature.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: So can i fetch DB details through cli ??

Comment: Actually i need to fetch DB details through aws sdk

Comment: Yeah, you can use Performance Insights with AWS Console, CLI and SDK as well.

Comment: Can you provide reference code or link for calling APIs

Comment: can you please specify which SDK? I mean programming language.

Comment: Its node js. And from cloudwatch we can't access DB size right? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: ooh, there is a metric in cloudwatch named 'FreeStorageSpace', which might be helpful for you.

Comment: you can find more information on this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html

Comment: But that is for freestoragespace. I want the DB size

Comment: Yeah, there is. But, only available for RDS Aurora. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/view-storage-aurora-cluster/

Comment: Bad luck, I am using Postgres